# Python - How to replace all matching text in a column by a reference table - which requires replacing multiple matching text within a cell

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Hi I'm totally new to Python but am hoping someone can show me the ropes.

I have a csv reference table which contains over 1000 rows with unique Find values, example of reference table:

```
|Find          |Replace     |
------------------------------
|D2-D32-dog    |Brown       |
|CJ-E4-cat     |Yellow      |
|MG3-K454-bird |Red         |
```

I need to do a find and replace of text in another csv file. Example of Column in another file that I need to find and replace (over 2000 rows):

```
|Pets                                  |
----------------------------------------
|D2-D32-dog                            |
|CJ-E4-cat, D2-D32-dog                 |
|MG3-K454-bird, D2-D32-dog, CJ-E4-cat  |
|T2- M45 Pig                           |
|CJ-E4-cat, D2-D32-dog                 |
```

What I need is for python to find and replace, returning the following, and if no reference, return original value:

```
|Expected output    |
---------------------
|Brown              |
|Yellow, Brown      |
|Red, Brown, Yellow |
|T2- M45 Pig        |
|Yellow, Brown      |
```

Thanking you in advance.

FYI - I don't have any programming experience, usually use Excel but was told that Python will be able to achieve this. So I have given it a go in hope to achieve the above - but it's returning invalid syntax error...

```
import pandas as pd

dfRef1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Downloads\Lookup.csv')
#File of Find and Replace Table

df= pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Downloads\Data.csv')
#File that contains text I want to replace

dfCol = df['Pets'].tolist()
#converting Pets column to list from Data.csv file 

for x in dfCol:
    Split = str(x).split(',')
#asking python to look at each element within row to find and replace

newlist=[]
for index,refRow in dfRef1.iteritems():
     newRow = []
     for i in Split:
              if i == refRow['Find']:
              newRow.append(refRow['Replace']
              else
              newRow.append(refRow['Find'])
              newlist.append(newRow)
    newlist

#if match found replace, else return original text
#When run, the code is Returning - SyntaxError: invalid syntax
#I've also noticed that the dfRef1 dtype: object
```

Am I even on the right track? Any advise is greatly appreciated. 
I understand the concept of Excel VLookup, however, because the cell value contains multiple lookup items which i need to replace within the same cell, I'm unable to do this in Excel.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, this is too broad a question. You will need to 'have a go' and then we can help. 

I suggest having a look at the [pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and use the `read_csv` function to read in the .csv file as a pandas.DataFrame object which you can then manipulate. 

I also suggest you read advice on how to write a good stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can use `pandas` to achieve your result learn more about pandas when you try to solve your problem and still can't do it you can search more about your problems.

Comment: It would be nice if you could specify the file format. Excel support multiple file format. As for processing them in Python, usually we use Pandas to read and manipulate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the excel file as CSV to make your life easier
then strip your file to contain only the table without any unnecessary information.

load the CSV file to python with pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
df_table1 = pd.read_csv("file/path/filename.csv")
df_table2 = pd.read_csv("file/path/other_filename.csv")

df_table1[['wanted_to_be_replaced_col_name']] = df_table2[['wanted_col_to_copy']]
```

for further informaion and more complex assignment go visit the pandas documentaion @ https://pandas.pydata.org/

hint: for large amount of columns check the iloc function